# Ajax query to ruby server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

I tries to make AJAX request to my ruby server from browser, but server throws this error It is in last string on the screenshot.[image: Error in the last string].
When I make request from terminal(python) everything is ok. What I do wrong?
My ruby server

```
 require 'sinatra'
    require 'json'
    
    post "/" do
      request.body.rewind  # in case someone already read it
      data = JSON.parse request.body.read
    
      "Hello #{data['name']}!"
    end
```

My ajax query

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4567/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: {"name":"b"}
            })
            .done(
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            )
```

Comment: What is the error? I only see the trace that shows up when you quit Sinatra

Comment: @maxpleaner in the last string

Comment: Does Sinatra need some extra code to listen for and support the OPTIONS method? 
 That is clearly the error and this happens in the browser (and not via python) because you're making an ajax request and the browser is doing CORS preflight checking.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What response I need to send to send to confirm cors as answer to options request?

Comment: @mrrogers help please

Comment: Maybe it would work if you used localhost instead of 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `sinatra-cross_origin` to your Gemfile.

After that, update your Sinatra app to include and configure the `cross_origin` settings as follows

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'

configure do
  enable :cross_origin
end

before do
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
end

options "*" do
  response.headers["Allow"] = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, X-User-Email, X-Auth-Token"
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
  200
end

post "/" do
  data = JSON.parse request.body.read

  "Hello #{data['name']}!"
end
```

Then you can make your Ajax request like this.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4567/',
  type: 'POST',
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: '{"name":"b"}',
})
  .done(
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  )
```

The difference here is adding `crossDomain: true`.

Putting these two together should log the right stuff after the Ajax call.

Note: Here we've added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"`.  If you know where your html is deployed and where the server sits, you may prefer to have that set to something specific so that it can't be accessed by *any* site.  If your html is deployed at `myapp.whateverdomain.com` and you might want your server to have something more like

```
response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "https://myapp.whateverdomain.com"
```

You can read more about CORS configuration [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)